# How to resolve composer package circular dependency of external package?

Tags: php, composer-php

See [Github issue](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/ReflectionDocBlock/pull/128#issuecomment-343654897), where this question originated.

**My package is `phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock`, it's not a dependency.**

---

I'm trying to update `phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock` to newer `phpunit/phpunit` dependency, that [started to use the package](https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy-phpunit#this-package-is-not-maintained-anymore-prophecy-is-supported-in-phpunit-directly-as-of-phpunit-45-making-this-package-useless) I update.

There is new circular dependency:

- (**this**) `phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock` package requires `phpunit/phpunit`
- `phpunit/phpunit` requires `phpspec/prophecy` (since `phpunit/phpunit` 4.5)
- `phpspec/prophecy` requires this `phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock` (**this**) package

In abstraction:

- A needs B
- B needs C (new one!)
- C needs A

#### Before - works

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.4"
    }
}
```

#### After - broken

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.5"
    }
}
```

When I run:

```
composer update
```

**Composer conflict output**:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock dev-phpunit -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[dev-phpunit].
    - phpspec/prophecy v1.3.1 requires phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock ~2.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5].
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.5.0 requires phpspec/prophecy ~1.3.1 -> satisfiable by phpspec/prophecy[v1.3.1].
    - Can only install one of: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.0, dev-phpunit].
    - Can only install one of: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.1, dev-phpunit].
    - Can only install one of: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.2, dev-phpunit].
    - Can only install one of: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.3, dev-phpunit].
    - Can only install one of: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.4, dev-phpunit].
    - Can only install one of: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.5, dev-phpunit].
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 4.5 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.5.0].
```

---

I've tried:

- `minimum-stability: dev`
- aliases `"phpunit/phpunit": "4.5 as 4.4"`

Any ideas how to approach this?

Comment: Have you tried requiring `phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock` before phpunit and explicitly install the package? Basically: Install C, Install A (requires B), Install B (requires C, but is already installed)

Comment: My pakage is `phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock` and it can't require itself. See [Github repository PR](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/ReflectionDocBlock/pull/128#issuecomment-343654897) for more

Comment: I've updated the question to make that clear, thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
"extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "4.x-dev"
    }
}
```

to `composer.json` of `phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock`.

This will allow you to use current master as version `4.x` which satisfies requirements

Downside is. You will have to update this section when moving on with versions.